# Disable Multiple User Sessions in Keycloak 19

Tags: keycloak

I want to disable multiple user sessions in Keycloak 19.
I tried following configuration but it did not worked.
[image]

Comment: Maybe this van help: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/limit-concurrent-sessions-per-user-account/866

Comment: This does not help as it does not describe the exact sequence of the flows.

Comment: I referred to this link: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10077 but still not able to fix this issue